# Is the 'recent achievements' icon helpful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, user-interface, achievements-dialog

In several recent and high-profile questions on Meta about the quality of questions and answers on SO, people have suggested that excessive 'gamification' leading to 'reputation chasing' is a problem. This was mainly in the context of people answering crappy questions to get the rep, but also about things like 'robot' reviewing to gain badges.

Every time I use SO while working (very often), I have the potential to be distracted away from what I am doing by an icon in the top left informing me about rep changes and new badges. Doesn't this just encourage people to spend their lives trying to amass invisible Internet points and shiny stuff, rather than to spend time thoughtfully exchanging ideas and knowledge?

Reputation has a purpose, and that purpose is to guide people to good questions and to trusted answers and answerers. We all know the purpose isn't to give people a dopamine kick, to allow them to think they have won the Internet, or to encourage them to try and find ways to optimize reputation scored while minimizing effort. Constant feedback about upvotes does exactly those things. (Constant feedback about messages is different - it is problematic in some similar ways, but much more important in how it allows people to discuss and respond to one another.)

Maybe that icon shouldn't be there at all, but could we at least have a preference to disable it?

Comment: Duplicate (but not on this site): [*Is there a way to turn off this disturbing green light from the status bar?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210118/146015)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Jonathan Because people disagree with jwg and his suggestion. Remember that votes work differently at meta.stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

Your comment about being distracted by the icon leads me to two different conclusions:

- you're so awesome that it's going off like a fireworks display. Congrats. Now get back to work.
- you have an attention disorder. There's pills for that. Or just don't look there. No... Don't. Look. There.

*Now back to the serious part of the answer...* **I think your assertion is tenuous at best**, especially when you use phrases like "*potential* to be distracted", or "constant feedback about up votes" (it gives feedback about down votes as well).

Personally I like the constant feedback. Not only does it alert you to positive rep changes, it alerts you to negative ones as well which gives you the oppotunity to spot (and fix) problems with your posts. It brings a level of interactivity to the site that is largely beneficial for those who actively participate.

As I mentioned in my comment above, it's [been suggested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210118/146015) and outright declined as a feature improvement. Pay attention to [user fredley's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210142/146015), he links to some scripts which may help.

Comment: The defined purpose of a 'notification icon' is to distract someone from something. If it isn't distracting it is a failure.

Comment: My point in this question is not mainly about the distraction. It is mainly about the reinforcement to the idea that SO is a game about getting a big rep, which you didn't address. This is why I posted here, where there has been a lot of discussion about this problem, rather than on M.SE.

Comment: @jwg Sort of - I would call it an *indicator icon* rather than a *notification* icon as it *indicates* changes rather than *demanding* attention. The one next to it that turns red when you've got comments is a notification icon because it demands attention.

Comment: That's not quite true. It resets when clicked on, so examining your latest rep changes is an action which it *demands* by design, rather than simply *indicating* total rep, for example.

Comment: @jwg That's why I mentioned that I think your assertion is tenuous - I think you will have a very hard time trying to show a link between that icon and gamification.

Comment: The link between that icon and gamification is pretty clear. If you had said the link between that icon and *rep chasing*, fair enough. The fact that you mentioned *gamification* kind of accepts that gamification is a problem. It isn't difficult to argue that a constantly updating score in the corner of the screen is gamification.

Comment: @jwg Yes, gamification has always been an issue, although not a huge issue. However if you think that people are gamifying simply to see that icon glow then... that's stretching credibility.

Comment: I don't think that and never said it.

Comment: @jwg Yep, you said it: *The link between that icon and gamification is pretty clear.*